# Multiplayer Photon 2

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

After many months, I made a multiplayer game in Unity 3d using Photon 2. How can I run the game on a second computer? If, for example, I want to play with a friend

Answer (score 0):

In Unity, go into file -> build and this should create an executable file that you can then run on the other computer.